# How to exclude multiple directories from bee pack

Tags: go, beego

How do I exclude multiple directories from bee pack tool?

`bee pack -ba "-tags prod" -exr=^userfiles$`

this excludes this particular directory. But I want to exclude directories named as userfiles, deploy, docs. I tried

`-exr=[^userfiles$,^deploy$,^docs$]`
`-exr=["^userfiles$","^deploy$","^docs$"]`

both of these didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since exr is a regexp, you could try and use (using the [re2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)) a composite:

```
-exr=^(?:userfile|deploy|docs)$
```

The [OP Joseph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770719/joseph) confirms the idea [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869580/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-from-bee-pack/29869610#comment47873395_29869610):

```
goop exec bee pack -ba "-tags prod" -exr="^(?:userfiles|deploy|tests|docs)$"
```

Comment: Exact syntax is:
`goop exec bee pack -ba "-tags prod" -exr="^(?:userfiles|deploy|tests|docs)$"`

Comment: @Joseph Great, it worked! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.